# Removing leading spaces in a text file

Tags: windows, linux, text, gnuwin32

I have a bunch of texts files although they all have spaces at the beginning of lines

e.g.

```
 testing 123
 download
 upload
```

would be

```
testing 123
download
upload
```

Preferably using a utility such as grep etc.

Comment: The answer is going to be different for linux and windows. Can you remove the tag for one of them (unless you happened to need the answer for both OS's)

Comment: Do you want to do this in place (ie. overwriting the original files) or into new files (so you keep the originals)?

Comment: @matzahboy that depends what you use, my perl solution is cross platform.

Comment: @Raoul good point. I was thinking shell script which isn't cross platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i -e's/^\s*//' yourfilenamehere
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`

```
sed 's/^ *//' file
```

This should work with Linux and your GNUWin Toolkit.

```
echo "     Line starting with spaces" | sed 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi -e 's/^\s+//' yourfilenamehere
```

Comment: Sorry, perl is arkward for me, as I would need to install it on a few hundred pc's

Comment: @Jay your post is tagged linux, >99% ship with Perl installed.